# Are ARIA attributes likes aria-label supposed to be translatable in HTML5?

Tags: html, selenium, accessibility, wai-aria

I dislike using ids to allow Selenium to more easily find an element. I figure Selenium should leverage an accessibility ARIA attribute which will not only make Selenium better but also be more accessible to screen readers. In a sense, a bot like WebDriver should rely on semantics like a REST API.

`aria-label` seems to be a good candidate, something like `<button aria-label="close-user-dialog">`, but are these attributes supposed to be translatable? That would break my Selenium requirement, which needs a unique id that does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes they are, and in general I'd discourage the use of aria-label anyway. Conveying information to AT users in ways not visible to regular users is considered something of an anti-pattern, because (a) that information is liable to be not maintained properly and (b) regular users can often benefit from that information.

If possible, use aria-labelledby instead, then your Selenium reference can use that without fear that it will be lost in translation.